# parallel execution of inference of deep learning model which are divided into parts

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, parallel-processing, neural-network, pytorch

Here I have a scenario of training a deep neural network(image classification n/w) say of 8 layers.
after training , I split the model in 4 parts each model part having 2 layers each.

Now i want to do the inference on my test image , technically speaking the image passed would move through every block to produce the final output which will be serial processing.
i.e
**total_time = time_taken_by_model_1 + time_taken_by_model_2 + time_taken_by_model_3 + time_taken_by_model_4**
Some thing like shown in below image

[image: fig 1.]

so my question is, instead of this serial computation ,Can I parallelize the inference computation such that time taken should be less than serialized inference from above **total_time** ( atleast half of the total_time from above case)
Any links/paper/blogs  about these problems can also be helpful

**EDIT** : all model parts will be on different devices(raspberry pi)

Answer (score -1):

You should look at [pipelining a parallel model](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/model_parallel_tutorial.html).
For a single example, you cannot save time, but if you have many samples to classify you can benefit from pipelining them.

Comment: thanks for reply..@Shai, I hav added edit block...Help will be apprciated